# Laravel - How to merge relationship results?

Tags: laravel

how can i merge laravel relationship results in to one object?

MyController.php

```
    public function getUser($id) {
return TournamentUser::where('customer_id','=', $id)->with('user')->get();
    }
```

MyModel.php

```
    public function user() {
return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Customer','customer_id', 'customer_id');
    }
```

returning result :

> `[{
>   "id":1,
>   "tournament_id":3,
>   "customer_id":2016827550,
>   "point":0,
>   "user":{
>   "id":1,
>   "customer_id":2016827550,
>   "nickname":"OMahoooo"
>   }
>   }]`

as expected query returns user section as array but i  expect result like this :

> `[{
>   "id":1,
>   "tournament_id":3,
>   "customer_id":2016827550,
>   "point":0,
>   "nickname":"OMahoooo"
>   }]`

only get nickname section without user array. I hope you understand me. 
Sorry for my english , have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the data and remap it manually using [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map) method. I've just tested this code and it works perfectly with `hasOne()` relationship:

```
$users = TournamentUser::where('customer_id', $id)->with('user')->get();
$users->map(function ($i) {
    $i->nickname = $i->user->nickname; // Set related nickname.
    unset($i->user); // Delete user data from the collection.
    return $i;
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), but in this case, you'll meet the [N+1 problem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).